# Is it possible to return a value from setTimeout without a callback function?

Tags: javascript

Long story short, is it possible to do something like this without a callback function?

```
function foo(){
  return 'foo';
}
function bar(){
  x = setTimeout(foo, 2000);
  alert(x);
}
```

Without modifying the foo() function. Adding an intermediary function would be fine, but I don't think that'll accomplish anything.

Long story:
I'm looking to simulate window.showModalDialog via window.open without having to do significant code rewrites everywhere the dang thing was used. The only suggestions I have found are to use a while loop or ping the server to simulate sleep(). Neither solution strikes me as ideal, and I am wondering if there is any other way to do something like this minus the callback function method?

Comment: Would [Web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_web_workers) do what you need?

Comment: The answers aren't entirely accurate and wanted to add one point of clarification.  `setTimeout` does return a value, just not what you expect.  It returns the id of the timer, so that you can, for whatever reason, *cancel* the timeout and prevent it from running.  Edit: an edit to this response clarifies things accurately: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13730735/1795053

Comment: no, Web workers won't do it, esp since I'm shooting for IE support back till 7, thanks for the info Eli looked through jAndy's answer, didn't know

Comment: Remember, `setTimeout` is *not* supposed to be used like a pause or delay.  The point is that you can set it free to go off and do its thing while continuing on forward.  For the code in your example to work, the function would have to stop for 2 seconds between lines before `x` was ready for the `alert()`.  If you want it to function like a delay, try continuing your program in `foo()`, or have `foo()` call another function that continues the program.

Comment: Sandy, that's exactly what I had wanted, a delay without having foo() call another function. I guess I wanted my cake and to eat it as well :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: *No*.

I would answer in more detail, but since you asked for a "short" answer and ruled another "callback" out", there is only this left to say.

`setTimeout` will *always* return an identifier to *clear* the timeout and anything you *return* from the function you pass into `setTimeout` is getting ignored.

Comment: Thanks for the details, I wasn't really asking for a short answer, I meant I was giving a short / long scenario of my problem. However I appreciate the short answer, and the details. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

No, that is not possible. Yet, you could return something that [represents the future value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises) and lets you add the callback afterwards: a [Promise](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Promises).

Comment: hmm, thank you for that, looks interesting this may help me solve my problem, will explore and report further

Comment: hmm, no not quite, still requires a call back to populate the data and modification to the foo() function which is what I was trying to avoid, thanks for the tip though, maybe more useful in other places, I was hoping for some form of a blocking the way alert, confirm, and showModalDialog do

Comment: No, JavaScript is single-threaded, and does not allow blocking. It's simply impossible.

Comment: yeah, that's what I feared, sucks that they let those 3 things block and nothing else, I've found while based hacks, but pinging the CPU while I have a window.open going is not an ideal solution either...

Answer (score 0):

Refactor your design. You can more than likely implement what you are looking for with a timeout, but not like this. Don't buck convention, use a callback

```
function foo(){
 alert('foo');
}
function bar(){
 setTimeout(foo, 2000);
}
```

As far as saving the timeout in a variable goes, that is used for clearing timeouts.

```
timeoutID = setTimeout();
window.clearTimeout(timeoutID);
```

Answer (score 0):

setTimout already returns something, but it's not the value of the evalauated expression. It returns a timout object that lets you abort and do other stuff later if you need to. setTimeout just tells a function to execute in the future.

If you wanted to get a functionality that might work for your circumstance, you could use something like this:

```
var answer = null;
setTimeout(function() {
    /*do something to 'answer'*/
    answer = 14;
}, 1000);
```

NOTE: This means that you have little control over when "answer" is set. That is why it's always best to use call backs because you're telling your code "in the future, when you have a value, perform this function on it".